# Linq to Entities: Where clause containing ToString fails

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I can do the following:

```
 var result = DB.Products.ToList()  // .AsEnumerable() too
              .Where( p => p.ID.ToString() == ViewModel.ID);
```

But it pulls all the products instead of only what I want, then filters locally.  Without the ToList(), it fails to find/use the .ToString method in the projection.  The ViewModel.ID is string from the client.

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7298535/84424) talks about the same issue, minus the where clause, but the answer doesn't fix pulling every product locally.

My ViewModel.ID is string because knockout.js converts it from numeric to string if the user changes the value.  I figured I would pursue this first as it's probably easier to rule it out.

Comment: Despite having to pull back all the data, how does `Where` with the `ToString` "fail"?

Comment: @pst: "*Without* the ToList(), *it fails* to find/use the .ToString method in the projection." -OP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are approaching the problem from the wrong direction. Convert `ViewModel.ID` back to integer (`int.Parse`), then you can offload the filtering back to the database. This is going to be far better than a workaround to cast `p.ID` to a string at the database, a move that would likely defeat any indexing on the value at the DB.

Comment: Your are definitely correct.  The best place I've found so far to translate these comparisons is using a query object or specification that returns a lambda expression.  This way it can accept string and output int.  TYVM